# Print doesn't use ad-hoc __str__() or __repr__() methods

Tags: python, string, printing, protocols, repr

I'm having a problem in Python 3.4 and would appreciate any help and/or explanation:

Basically I have a class with a function that should return an instance of another class, but with a modified string representation so that I can later print() that instance and see the Stuff added in that function.

What I don't understand is that even though I seem to be able to change the **str** and **repr** methods of that instance, print() will still use the original representation.

This is a boiled-down example that essentially shows what I tried:

```
class A():
  def __str__(self):
    return('AAA')
class B():
  def output(self):
    return('BBB')
  def run(self):
    a = A()
    print("if str(a)({}) equals a.__str__()({})...".format(str(a), a.__str__()))
    a.__str__ = self.output
    a.__repr__ = self.output
    print("... why not now? (str(a) = {} while a.__str__() = {}".format(str(a), a.__str__()))
    return a
b = B()
a=b.run()
print("print a: {}, str(a): {}, a.__str__(): {}, a.__repr__():{}".format(a, str(a), a.__str__(), a.__repr__()))
```

Can someone please explain this to me?
Thanks for your time, guys!

Edit: forgot the output, sorry:

```
[xxx@localhost ~]$ python test.py
if str(a)(AAA) equals a.__str__()(AAA)...
... why not now? (str(a) = AAA while a.__str__() = BBB
print a: AAA, str(a): AAA, a.__str__(): BBB, a.__repr__():BBB
```

Edit: Thanks Martijn Pieters for the explanation!

```
I changed my code to :

class A():
  def __init__(self):
    self.str = 'AAA'

  def __str__(self):
    return(self.str)

class B():

  def run(self):
    a = A()
    a.str = 'BBB'
    print(a, str(a), a.__str__())
    return a

b = B()
a=b.run()

print("print a: {}, str(a): {}, a.__str__(): {}".format(a, str(a), a.__str__()))
```

And I now get the output I want:

```
python test.py
BBB BBB BBB
print a: BBB, str(a): BBB, a.__str__(): BBB
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you included the output of running the code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special methods are always called on the *type*; for instances, that is the class. See the [Special method lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup):

> For custom classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in the object’s instance dictionary.

This means that you cannot add `__str__` or `__repr__` methods to the *instance* and expect those to be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
a.__class__.__str__ = self.output
a.__class__.__repr__ = self.output
```

But in Python2.7 your original code works correctly. Hmm.